# How to redirect to a page and pass data to the redirected url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

```py
def view_post(request, post_id):
    """Display a blog post"""
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)

    context = {'blogpost': blogpost}
    return render(request, 'blogs/blogpost.html', context)

def new_post(request):
    """Create a new blog post"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = BlogPostForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = BlogPostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:index')
    
    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)

def edit_post(request, post_id):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with current blogpost.
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=blogpost)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=blogpost, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        view_post(request,post_id)

    # Display form with original contents
    context = {'blogpost': blogpost,'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

The code above is for a blog site where users can create, edit, and view blog-posts. Edit_post should process a user's edited post, and then redirect to the post that has been edited. Redirect doesn't allow data to be sent to my knowledge, so I tried to nest a function to no avail.

I've seen online that cookies / messages may be a solution. If so, how might I implement it?

EDIT:
I've added

```
        print("DEBUG returning HttpResponseRedirect of reverse of view_post")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view_post, args=[post_id]))
```

to the end of the else for edit_post, replacing the previous view_post attempt at a redirect. After submitting post data, however, I receive the error `NoReverseMatch at /post/edit_post/1/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

I found that it does take parameters. The following code achieves what I needed:
`return redirect('blogs:view_post', post_id=post_id)`

`blogs:view_function` was needed for the reverse to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Redirect doesn't allow data to be sent to my knowledge, so I tried to nest a function to no avail.

If after edit you want to be redirected to detail view of `Post`, you can just use `HttpResponseRedirect` object and `reverse` function. For example:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view_post, args=[post_id]))`